# SQLModel - Adding comments to a tables

Tags: python, sqlmodel

I couldn't find in the docs or in examples on the web how to add a comment to a table, so that it's also written in the corresponding SQL DB when the schema is created.

Is it possible in SQLModel? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution on the github issues of SQLModel; please see the attached link.
https://github.com/tiangolo/sqlmodel/issues/492#issuecomment-1309849747